# Sum each item in a Panda Series and sort by largest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have imported a csv file as a pandas dataframe and am trying to perform the below.

Data Frame Model:

```
         STATE       County                  POP
1       Alabama      Autauga County          54571
2       Alabama      Baldwin County         182265
3       Alabama      Barbour County          27457
...
3168  Wisconsin         Wood County          74749
3170    Wyoming       Albany County          36299
3171    Wyoming     Big Horn County          11668
3172    Wyoming     Campbell County          46133
```

1.) Get a list of top two counties per State

2.) Get the sum of the top two counties for each State

3.) List the top two states with the largest population sorted from largest to smallest

I was able to accomplish item 1 using the below. Is there a way I can remove the index value from this output?

```
census_df.groupby('STATE')['POP'].nlargest(2)

STATE                    
Alabama               37       658466
                      49       412992
Alaska                71       291826
                      76        97581
Arizona               106     3817117
                      109      980263
Arkansas              174      382748
                      118      221339
```

But when I try to sum each item in the Series it is summing the entire series.

```
x.sum()
```

Is there a way to sum each item in the series?  Also, Im not sure I am using the most efficient method to gather this info. Any help would be appreciated.

My desired output would be:

Top two most populated states:

```
STATE     POP_SUM                  
Arkansas  382748
Wisconsin 271431
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly- you can pass `level` argument to sum to keep the grouping by state:

```
x.sum(level=0)
```

Comment: Wow so simple. Thanks! That helped a lot.